# Working with a stream of streams

Tags: java, exception, java-stream

I want to work out if I can do something like this. Suppose I have a stream of the numbers 1 - 20. I want to utilise a feature such as a drop 3 (limit or skip I guess in Java terms?) and produce a stream of streams that is the numbers:

1 - 20, 4 - 20, 7- 20, etc

then possibly flat map these alll into one stream. I've tried various combinations of using Stream.iterate primarily to generate streams from streams, but I keep geting an IllegalStateException saying the stream has already operated upon or closed.

For example one may expect this code:

```
  Stream.iterate(Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5), x -> x.skip(1).collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()).limit(5).flatMap(x -> x).forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));
```

To produce: 1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,3,4,5,4,5,5

But it doesn't, it throws an exception. Am I missing something obvious here. I know of a takeWhile operation but don't think it's out until Java 9.

EDIT: I have managed to get an ugly solution to what I was trying to achieve using the following:

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 20).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
Stream.iterate(list, x -> x.stream().skip(3).collect(Collectors.toList())).limit(7).map(x -> x.stream().limit(3).collect(Collectors.toList())).flatMap(List::stream).forEach(System.out::println);
```

So I have a list 1..20, then end up with a stream of lists 1..20, 4..20, 7..20, etc. If I then take the first 3 elements of each of these I end up with 1..3, 4..6, 7..9, etc. If I flatMap this, I get back to 1..20.

My question is, A. is there a way for me to not have to hardcode limit(7) above, so it automatically stops when I've processed all of the input element set, and B. I don't like having to collect into lists - can I not do this purely with streams prior to a collection at the end or even just printing after a flat map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for something like

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 20)
   .flatMap(i -> IntStream.rangeClosed(i, 20))
```

...which you can then do whatever you like with; e.g. `.forEach(System.out::println)`.

If you want to do this for every third number, you're better off doing something like

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 20/3)
  .map(i -> 3 * i + 1)
  .flatMap(i -> IntStream.rangeClosed(i, 20))
```

Comment: How do you produce "A", "B", "C", "B", "C", "C" from "A", "B", "C"?

Comment: I'd probably do it with `IntStream.range(0, 3).flatMap(i -> IntStream.range(i, 3)).mapToObj(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C")::get)`.

Comment: Couple of questions - so why am I getting an IllegalStateException with my code above? Also I wanted to in effect have an existing stream of say 1..20 and drop 3 elements from this so I get 4..20, then drop 3 from this, so I get 7..20, etc. In the end I want a stream of streams, or even a stream of lists would do that contains [[1..20],[4..20],[7..20 ... etc] with each new stream (or list) being defined by the content of the previous with results dropped. Furthermore, I wondered if it was then possible to take 3 from each of these streams/lists to end up with the original range of 1..20?

Comment: A Stream is good for only one use. You cannot use it, and separately use the same stream, skip one element, and use that.  If you want to reuse a stream, you will have to store it into an intermediate collection and get new streams from that each time.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar that you can do in haskell with take and drop operations, and getting a list of lists.

Comment: @Tranquility, yes, I'm familiar with what you can do along these lines in Haskell, but these work differently. You will end up having to do something along the lines I've described, either with IntStreams or at a minimum storing the stream you want to take different slices of into a collection.

Comment: That's what I was trying to do with the example code I put above - you will note I'm using iterate to generate one stream from another, but I was collecting inbetween this, as otherwise, nothing will happen until the terminal operation is ran. But I'm still getting an exception. Do you have any example of what you say of taking slices into a collection?

Comment: @Tranquility You have a `Stream<Stream<Integer>>`, and your one `Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5)` is used twice -- once for the first element of the `Stream<Stream<Integer>>`, unchanged, and once for the second element, when it's used as `x` in `x.skip(1).collect(toList()).stream())`.  It's still reusing things.  As far as slicing a collection goes, you need to have something like `Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`, and then you can do `list.subList(index, list.size())` to drop the first `index` elements from that list.  (You're almost certainly not going to be able to avoid using indexes at some point.)

Comment: ok, so I've figured I can do this: List<Integer> list = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 20).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
  Stream.iterate(list, x -> x.stream().skip(3).collect(Collectors.toList())).limit(7).forEach(System.out::println); and I get the output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10..
etc
However, is there a way to not have put a limit of hardcoded 7? can I force it to stop when I've got to an empty stream, or can i only do that with takeWhile? Furthermore, can I not do this with streams not lists?

Comment: Sure, that'll work.  Something along the lines I outlined above would be a lot simpler, though.

Comment: Lous, I've added an EDIT to my original question, to show you what I'm getting at.

Comment: @Tranquility the answer to both parts of your question is no.  Java streams aren't intended to be used in the same sorts of ways as the Haskell things you're trying to emulate.